I call the PHP file in the subfolder, but the .htaccess uses a weird rewrite
In the root I have files: .htaccess and page.php
In the /test/ subfolder I have files: define_session.php and write_session.php
.htaccess:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$ page.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3 [L,QSA]
# www.example.com/parameter1/parameter2/parameter3/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)?$ page.php?p1=$1&p2=$2 [L,QSA]
# www.example.com/parameter1/parameter2/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?p1=$1 [L,QSA]
#www.example.com/parameter1/

page.php
<?php
echo "Hello World";
// session_start();
// session_destroy();
?>

/test/session_define.php
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["session_test"] = "123456789";
?>

<a href="session_write.php">session_write.php</a>

/test/session_write.php
<?php
session_start();
echo "session_test:".$_SESSION["session_test"]."<br>";
?>

OK scenario:

In Google Chrome, I call the URL "domain"/test/session_define.php
I click on the link and I get to the "domain"/test/session_write.php page and I see the SESSION variable "1234578" listed.
Everything ok.

Error Scenario (in page.php I uncomment "delete sessions"):

In Google Chrome, I call the URL "domain"/test/session_define.php
I click the link and it goes to "domain"/test/session_write.php, but $_SESSION["session_test"] is not defined (it is removed because of page.php).

I am calling a specific php file (URL) in a subfolder and I thought that the condition could not be met:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?p1=$1 [L,QSA]
I don't understand how page.php can remove SESSION when I call PHP file "/test/session_define.php" directly.
There should be no rewrite using .htaccess.
In page.php, I have also intentionally stated: echo "Hello World"; but this doesn't show, only sessions are deleted.
Please what am I doing wrong? What am I getting wrong?
Thank you very much for your help.

"in page.php I uncomment "delete sessions"" - What exactly do you mean by that? Did you uncomment both lines //session_start(); and //session_destroy();? "There should be no rewrite using .htaccess" - exactly. From what you have posted here, page.php is never called. "it is removed because of page.php" - how do you know it is because of page.php?

Aside: Your regex are far too generic, they should be made more restrictive (which might help resolve the issue) to only match the expected requests. eg. ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$ matches almost anything. eg. What are you expecting to happen to a request for /param1/param2/param3/param4/? Is /param1/param2/ a URL with 3 or 2 params? What can your "params" contain?

Aside (continued): By making the regex more restrictive you might be able to remove the dependency on the filesystem checks (which are relatively inefficient - and you have 3 of them). Relying on filesystem checks can be problematic if you have front-end proxies (in front of Apache) that handle direct file requests.

What is your testing environment? What version of Apache?

@MrWhite I tested this problem on two VMS:
PHP Version 7.4.33 - Apache/2.4.62 (Debian) and PHP Version 5.6.40-0+deb8u12 - Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

@MrWhite If I leave the //session_start(); and //session_destroy(); lines commented out in page.php, the session variable in the /test/session_write.php script will be written without any problems.
But if I uncomment both session_start(); and session_destroy(); lines in page.php, the session is not written on the /test/session_write.php page.
I also tried commenting the #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?p1=$1 [L,QSA] line in .htaccess, and in that case the session on the /test/session_write.php page is also written correctly.

@MrWhite I try Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome and Opera browsers. When I change the comment for deleting sessions in page.php, I have to refresh with CTRL+F5 (not just F5) so that the change in behavior is reflected between scenario 1 and 2.
Is it possible that browsers remember that page.php was previously pushed (rewrite) and should/shouldn't delete sessions?

If a page doesn't explicitly specify the location of a favicon, some browsers try and request /favicon.ico by default. If you do not have such a file, this would trigger your last rule, and be rewritten to /page.php?p1=favicon.ico. Boom, session nuked. Go use your browser dev tools, network panel, and check if such a request is indeed happening.

@C3roe Yes! That's the problem.
Sorry for my schoolboy mistake. I knew I had to have the favicon.ico, but I just put it in the /test/ subdirectory, not the root.
Thank you very much for explaining exactly how the missing favicon.ico causes the problem.

If a page doesn't explicitly specify the location of a favicon, some browsers try and request /favicon.ico by default.
If you do not have such a file, this would trigger your last rule, and be rewritten to /page.php?p1=favicon.ico. So your session gets destroyed by that request.
